# Batch file to open .sql file and "execute as Script"

Tags: automation, toad

I am trying to create a Batch file to open .sql file and execute the queries in .sql file but instead of execute each query, I want to run all at once "execute as Script".

Below is the Code which is executing only one query

```
echo start
cls
C:
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\
%systemroot%\Syswow64\cmd.exe /C toad.exe -c User_Name/password@Database -f "C:\My Code\Stored SQL\example.sql" /exec
CLOSEToad
Exit    
:END
CLS
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please specify what issue are facing so we can help you.

Comment: Which database do you use? Why do you want to involve TOAD (a GUI tool) into such a task? Why wouldn't you rather create an operating system batch script which would call your .SQL file and execute it - the way you tried now, but by calling database's command line tool (such as SQL*Plus for Oracle).

Comment: Hi Yes I am using toad and now I am able to open toad & run the .sql file as procedure. But I am not able to exit toad. The exit command or EXIT /B or Close command is not working in DOS.

Comment: Also is there a way to get spool file from toad ???